# is there a way to add "\n" to gridview so that the display can look good

Tags: c#, asp.net

is there a way to add "\n" constant to a gridview so that the display can look good in asp.net c#.

I have a column in database that contains a summary of few things i have stored.
While retrieving and displaying it on a grid view i want clear separations so is there a way of how to add a \n constant ?

Comment: on what basis you will add /n

Comment: use fixed width column. So content will be wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

If you adding from HTML
use **`<br/>`**

If you are in C# use environment new line like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
sb.Append("blah, blah, blah"); 
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine); 
sb.Append("more blah, blah, blah");

string message = sb;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide fixed width to gridview column and also need below css for grid and columns.

```
.gridView
{
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.col
{
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you cannot use `\n` on HTML. But why don't you try `<br/>`? I think it is the right way.

Comment: Summary is loaded from db, so adding `<br/>` between summary lines may be difficult.

Comment: replacing `\n` with `<br>`?